# Jquery validate exception - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Very simple requirement, validate the field whether a positive number or not.

please refer to the js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/DJMmm/5/

**HTML CODE**

```
<form id="new_leavetype_form" action = "<%=path %>/admin/create.go">

     <input name="default_days" id="default_days_id" type="text"  />      
     <button id="submit_button" type="button">Submit</button>

</form>
```

**JS CODE**

```
$().ready(function(){
    $("#new_leavetype_form").validate({
        rules:{
            default_days: { number: true, required:true, PositiveNumber:true }
        }
    });

    $("#submit_button").click(function(){
        $("#new_leavetype_form").submit();
    });

})
```

**Question**

if fill letter(s) like 'abc' into the filed, while the filed lost focus, the validation was fired properly, however if the input is a number will cause the exception: 'Cannot call method 'call' of undefined '

I really don't know what caused this exception, please help, thank you.

Comment: You haven't defined the `PositiveNumber` validation method.

Comment: there is no rule saying `PositiveNumber`

Comment: isn't it a default method?

Comment: No. The default methods are listed here: http://jqueryvalidation.org/category/methods/

Comment: Where did `PositiveNumber` come from?  In other words, did you just make it up?

Comment: BTW- you can get rid of your entire `.click()` handler function by simply changing your `button` to `type="submit"`.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/3tuzK/

Comment: Also, [`$().ready()` is not the recommended format](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: @Sparky, the reason I never use submit type button is I have to do some other logic calculation before the form was submitted, here I removed that part

Comment: why it's not recommended?

Comment: Click on [the link I provided and read the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: Any logic you need to run before the form is submitted is typically put inside the `submitHandler` callback function of the plugin.  It fires upon click of the submit button when the form is valid.  Conversely, the `invalidHandler` fires upon click of the submit button when the form is not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no validation rule with name `PositiveNumber`.

Either you need to create a new rule or you can set the min rule to achieve the dame

```
$("#new_leavetype_form").validate({
    rules: {
        default_days: {
            number: true,
            required: true,
            min: 0
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cyrbA/)

Comment: jquery validate needs to state the missing rule name in the error message.